# Tab fragment changing action bar spinner

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I have fragment activity, with tab fragments. like this.

[image]

But when ever I tap on second tab, spinner on action bar becomes empty, like this.

[image]

I think it would be a common problem, but if it is not tell me I'll provide some code also.

I'm not doing any thing which is related to it in on tab change but I'm its code that might help you.

```
mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    InterestTabFragment tabOneFrgment = (InterestTabFragment) fragmentManager
                .findFragmentByTag("tab1");

    InteractionTabFragment tabTwoFrgment = (InteractionTabFragment) fragmentManager
                            .findFragmentByTag("tab2");

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if (tabOneFrgment != null && tabOneFrgment.isVisible()) {
        if (isInterestDataChanged) {                            
            // delete cache filed of interest
            }
        }else if(tabTwoFrgment != null && tabTwoFrgment.isVisible()){
            if (isInteractionDataChanged) {                         
            // delete cache filed of interaction

            }
        }else{
        if (isHangoutDataChanged) {
            // delete cache filed of hangout
            }

            }
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            });
```

This is inside OnCreateOptionMenu

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spListOpt);
spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
spinner.setAdapter(YearSpinnerAdapter);
spinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner);
```

And this is call for data, I'm setting adapter in its post execute code.

```
    class joingYearCall extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        String responseString = null;
        responseString = HttpManager.GetData(uri[0]);           
            JSONObject joiningResult;
            JSONObject year;
            try {
                joiningResult = new JSONObject(responseString);
                year = joiningResult.getJSONObject("ProfileInfoResult");
                joiningYear = Integer.parseInt(year.getString("joiningYear"));
                items.clear();
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                int currentYear = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                items.add("All");
                while(currentYear >= joiningYear)
                {
                    items.add(String.valueOf(currentYear--));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {                 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        spinner.setAdapter(YearsSpinnerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }
}
```

And this is my adapter.

```
    private SpinnerAdapter YearsSpinnerAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {

    private TextView text;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.spinner_hint_item, null);
        }
        text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTarget);
        text.setSingleLine(true);
        if (!selected) {
            Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.time_stalk);
            img.setBounds( 0, 0, 30, 30 );
            text.setCompoundDrawables( img, null, null, null );
        } else {
            text.setText(items.get(position));
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null);
        }
        text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTarget);
        text.setSingleLine(true);
        text.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                selected = true;
                ((BaseAdapter) YearsSpinnerAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }
        });
        text.setText(items.get(position));
        return convertView;
    };
};
```

Comment: Are you changing a fragment onTab click?

Comment: I have `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost` in xml file, and then adding tabs like this

Comment: mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),      android.R.id.tabcontent);    mTabHost.addTab(      mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(        getResources().getString(R.string.interest)),      InterestTabFragment.class, null);

Comment: What is your InterestTabFragment.class? Is it activity or fragment ?

Comment: I have added on tab changed code, please have a look on it. May be some thing is wrong with it.

Comment: Can you post ypur FragmentActivity code ?

Comment: Which part? as its too much

Comment: where have you populated actionBar spinner with data?

Comment: okay I'm editing my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66381/discussion-between-yawar-and-techhelper).